# Substract a part of a string considering some delimiters in php

Tags: php, substr

I have a variable in php witch can have this shape:

```
$a = 'help&type=client';
$b = 'account#client';
$c = 'info&type=client#new';
```

I need to create a substract function that will work like this:

```
echo myFunction($a); //&type=client
echo myFunction($b); //#client
echo myFunction($c); //&type=client#new
```

I will rate the more simplified answere.

Comment: How are you deciding which characters are the delimiter here? Is it just that you want the last name/value pair of the URL params *or* the URL fragment? What if it has both? Can you clarify the rules?

Comment: This are: & or # . I need something simplified

Comment: It seems to me you're actually in need of [the `parse_url` function](http://php.net/parse_url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the simplest way would be using [strpbrk](http://php.net/strpbrk).

```
$a = 'help&type=client';
$b = 'account#client';
$c = 'info&type=client#new';
echo strpbrk($a, '&#') . PHP_EOL; //&type=client
echo strpbrk($b, '&#') . PHP_EOL; //#client
echo strpbrk($c, '&#') . PHP_EOL; //&type=client#new
```

Comment: And if you want to echo $c, what happends?

Comment: @paulalexandru , desired result.

Comment: Thanks man, your answere is the best i found here, 1 line answere. Thank you very much. It works exactly as i want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for this

```
preg_match('[^help](.*)', $help, $match)
echo $match[0]; //&type=client
```

and

```
preg_match('[^account](.*)', $help, $match)
echo $match[0]; //#client
```

You can see this website: http://regex101.com/r/zR9eD1/1 for more information about these expressions.

Just a quick explanation:
we do NOT match 'help' and we DO match everything else (after 'help')

edit:
If you only have & or # as a delimiter you can use this:

```
preg_match('([#].+)', $help, $match)
echo $match[0]; //#client
```

This matches everything starting with a #

Comment: I need something general, because i can have more pages not only account and help. We should counsider the & or the # delimiter

Answer (score 0):

myFunction would be something like this:

```
function myFunction($string) {

    $amp = strpos($string, '&');
        if($amp) {
            return substr($string,$amp,strlen($string)-$amp);
        } else {
            $hash= strpos($string, '#');
            return substr($string,$hash,strlen($string)-$hash);
        }
}
```

You might have to change `if($amp)` to `if($amp > 0)` depending on what the output of strpos is.

Comment: I think your answer is good, but i want to wait a little more to see if someone comes with something more simplified.

Comment: Just omit the last argument of `substr`, it's a pointless `strlen` call: omitting the argument will default to _"the rest of the string"_

Answer (score 0):

What about this.

```
$re = "/[&#]([a-z=]+)/"; 
$str = "help&type=client\naccount#client"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

http://regex101.com/r/cW3yL6/1

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `preg_split`:

```
function myFunction($var) {
            return $var . "\n";
        }

$a = 'help&type=client';
$b = 'account#client';

$as = preg_split('/(\w+)/', $a, 2); 
$bs = preg_split('/(\w+)/', $b, 2); 

echo myFunction($as[1]);  // &type=client
echo myFunction($bs[1]);  // #client
```